# How to run MSTest with WinAppDriver from C# code?

Tags: c#, cmd, uwp, mstest, winappdriver

I am able to execute MSTest with WinAppDriver from a command line with

```bash
mstest /testcontainer:C:\Users\...\dev\WinAppDriver\Samples\C#\AlarmClockTest\bin\Debug\AlarmClockTest.dll
```

Now I have to do the same from another UWP application. I am attempting to do it with Process class.
My code:

```
string filename = @"C:\Users\...\dev\WinAppDriver\Samples\C#\AlarmClockTest\bin\Debug\AlarmClockTest.dll";

try
{
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "mstest /testcontainer:" + filename;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        _ = process.Start();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

When I am executing this code, I am getting cmd prompt opened at my UWP project's directory's `bin/x86/Debug/projectname` directory. The command to trigger a test had not been executed. I got same results when I replaced an argument with `@ECHO OFF ECHO Hello World!`.

Comment: Implemented with WPF and VSTest. Works well.